# Bitcoin, BTC.com and monitoring double-spend attempts

Tags: mining-pools, doublespend

I'm reading [Analysis of hashrate-based double-spending](https://bitcoil.co.il/Doublespend.pdf) article. On page 10 there's a table listing probability of successful double-spend attack in relation to required number of confirmation.

Looking at [hashrate distribution](https://www.blockchain.com/pools) I can see that BTC.com now owns 20% of network hash-rate. Given the numbers in the table in the article, it makes me wonder whether there have been any publicly revealed double-spend attacks by BTC.com or other major pools. BTC.com now has roughly 20% chance of successful double-spend attack against merchants waiting for just 2 confirmations.

Are there any *watchmen* monitoring the nefarious activities of mining pools on Bitcoin network akin to [Certificate Transparency](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/) which monitors certificate authorities in PKI?